# How to detect landscapeRight to landscapeLeft orientation change in react native?

Tags: react-native, orientation, landscape, iphone-x

I need to apply different styles on orientation change between two landscape positions i.e landscapeRight to landscapeLeft or vice versa in React Native? I know how to detect between portrait and landscape, just need a listener between two landscape positions in REACT NATIVE!
Thanks!

Comment: the stable library to handle orientation is [`yamill/react-native-orientation`](https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation)

Answer (score 4):

You would have to use an external dependency to manage this. Something like `react-native-orientation-locker` can give you what you want. This option requires you to be using a full `react-native` project as it will require you to link native code, so it **will not** work in `Expo`. You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-orientation-locker). Below are the basic usage instructions from the repo.

You can install it in the following way:

```
npm install react-native-orientation-locker --save
react-native link react-native-orientation-locker
```

There are a few extra steps that you need to do after you have linked it.

#### Configuration

iOS

Add the following to your project's `AppDelegate.m`:

```
+#import "Orientation.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

// ...

+- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
+  return [Orientation getOrientation];
+}

@end
```

Android

Add following to android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
  ....
  + android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
  ....
</activity>
```

Implement onConfigurationChanged method (in `MainActivity.java`)

```
// ...

+import android.content.Intent;
+import android.content.res.Configuration;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

+   @Override
+   public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
+       super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
+       Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
+       intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
+       this.sendBroadcast(intent);
+   }

    // ......
}
```

## Getting the orientation:

Then you can set a listener where you want to access the orientation, usually you add this in the `componentDidMount` and remove move it in `componentWillUnmount`.

Here is some example code that you can use to set it up.

```
import Orientation from 'react-native-orientation-locker';


_onOrientationDidChange = (orientation) => {
  if (orientation === 'LANDSCAPE-LEFT') {
    //do something with landscape left layout
  } 
  if (orientation === 'LANDSCAPE-RIGHT') {
    //do something with landscape right layout
  } 
};

componentWillMount() {
  //The getOrientation method is async. It happens sometimes that
  //you need the orientation at the moment the js starts running on device.
  //getInitialOrientation returns directly because its a constant set at the
  //beginning of the js code.
  var initial = Orientation.getInitialOrientation();
  if (initial === 'PORTRAIT') {
    //do stuff
  } else {
    //do other stuff
  }
},

componentDidMount() {

  Orientation.getAutoRotateState((rotationLock) => this.setState({rotationLock}));
  //this allows to check if the system autolock is enabled or not.

  Orientation.lockToPortrait(); //this will lock the view to Portrait
  //Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft(); //this will lock the view to Landscape
  //Orientation.unlockAllOrientations(); //this will unlock the view to all Orientations

  //get current UI orientation
  /*
  Orientation.getOrientation((orientation)=> {
    console.log("Current UI Orientation: ", orientation);
  });

  //get current device orientation
  Orientation.getDeviceOrientation((deviceOrientation)=> {
    console.log("Current Device Orientation: ", deviceOrientation);
  });
  */

  Orientation.addOrientationListener(this._onOrientationDidChange);
},

componentWillUnmount () {
  Orientation.removeOrientationListener(this._onOrientationDidChange);
}
```

This will mean that in your `_onOrientationDidChange` function it will receive on of the following:

- `'PORTRAIT'`
- `'LANDSCAPE-LEFT'` camera left home button right
- `'LANDSCAPE-RIGHT'` camera right home button left
- `'PORTRAIT-UPSIDEDOWN'`
- `'UNKNOWN'`